# I want to validate if given email address is exists in paypal? I need to verify if the paypal email they provided me exists or not?

Tags: paypal

I want to give payments to my customers, for that purpose I am getting their email, I want to verify is that email address exists in paypal or not!

I searched and found **payment identity API** which I tried but that only provides me **my data**! Here is the [LINK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1/) of that API.

I have also found **Adaptive payment** get verified status API but it is depreciated. Here is its [Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-accounts/api/get-verified-status/).

Also found this link https://www.paypal.com/us/verified/pal=emailaddress to verify, but it doesn't work also! I got it from paypal Community [Question](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/how-can-i-verify-an-email-address-before-sending-money/td-p/50702).

Anyone here who can help me out this issue! Or if any one can help me in [Connect With Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/) I am stuck on 6th step! This would also be used!

Comment: Why would they lie to you?

Comment: well its for validating and removing any sort of errors!

Comment: That’s important to avoid typo

Answer (score 0):

This is generally an unnecessary thing to implement.

But if you really must have this feature, you can indeed use [Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/), formerly known as Log in with PayPal).

Your question mentions being stuck but does not provide any technical detail about your problem or what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have posted the question for connect with paypal you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479783/anyone-who-have-used-paypal-connect-integration-paypal-connect-that-is-used-to)

Comment: I disagree on the unnecessary, what if you have a market place and you want to prevent confusion and support tickets for users who didn't get their pay because of a typo in their email. Or your payment batch gets truncated because of a failure that you didn't anticipate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the paypal user's email address, you could check if there is a Paypal avatar associated with it, if not, it's not a valid paypal email account.

With the AvatarAPI service, using the "Paypal" provider, you send a HTTP post to https://avatarapi.com/v2/api.aspx request of

```
   { 
        "username" : "##username##",
        "password" : "###password##",
        "email" : "#PAYPAL-EMAIL-ADDRESS##",
        "provider" : "Paypal"
    }
```

and if you get a response such as

```
 {
    "Name": "Whatever Company Ltd",
    "Image": "https://pics.paypal.com/00/s/YTUwMmE3NDMtNDQ5Yi00ZDEyLThmZDktYmZmOTI0ZjM0Njcw/file_26.PNG",
    "Valid": true,
    "City": "",
    "Country": "",
    "IsDefault": true
}
```

then it's valid, or this if it's invalid:

```
   {
        "success": false,
        "error": "Nothing found"
    }
```

Comment: It does not work with paypal as a provider anymore: https://www.avatarapi.com/v2/providers.aspx